# How to customize schema in pyspark to_json function

Tags: python, json, dataframe, pyspark

I have a dataframe like this

```
+---------+-----+
|component|offer|
+---------+-----+
|Hero     |Msg  |
|Hero     |MTC  |
+---------+-----+
```

I want to achieve something like this

```
+---+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |json                                                               |
+---+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |{"component":{0:"Hero",1:"Hero"},"offer":{0:"Msg",1:"MTC"}}        |
+---+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I am almost there by using below piece of code

```
df = df.withColumn("id",F.lit(1))
w = pyspark.sql.window.Window().orderBy(F.col('id'))
df = df.withColumn("row_num", F.row_number().over(w) - 1)
df = df.groupBy("id").agg(F.map_from_arrays(F.collect_list("row_num"), F.collect_list("component")).alias("component"),
F.map_from_arrays(F.collect_list("row_num"),F.collect_list("offer")).alias("offer"))
df = df.withColumn("json", F.to_json(F.struct("component", "offer")))
```

The only problem I am getting while converting the data into json by using to_json() it's converting the row_num(which is an integer into string).So instead of my desirable json I am getting a json like  *{"component":{"0":"Hero","1":"Hero"},"offer":{"0":"Msg","1":"MTC"}}*

Can please someone help me to achieve this?
Can you please also suggest an efficient way to achieve this?

Note- I am not looking for to convert pyspark df to pandas df to achieve this

Comment: You can not have integer as JSON key.